# Jenkins Update Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")") Execute Shell

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am getting an error when trying to run a build on my Jenkins server. The following is what the output is showing. This happened after I updated to the latest version of Jenkins. I have also verified that all plugins are up to date.

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson229576663898687231.sh
/tmp/hudson229576663898687231.sh: 1: /tmp/hudson229576663898687231.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Further debugging it appears that anytime I add an execute shell build option the error is thrown. For example inside the execute shell block.

```
ls -al;
```

Also the Jenkins installation is on an Ubuntu 12.10 machine.

Comment: Who can help without looking at the script?

Comment: What script this is just a basic jenkins build. It deletes that script before I can access it. Is there a way to have jenkins not delete it?

Comment: It appears that anytime I use execute shell in the build options it throws this error.

Comment: What version of Jenkins are you on?

Comment: I am using version 1.553 which I updated yesterday why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After further debugging I have figured out what was happening. Jenkins use to default to

```
#!/bin/sh
```

but not appears not to default to that. I added that on top of my command script and it works just fine now.

Comment: Fantastic!  This broke several of my builds and was driving me nuts.  Simple fix!

Comment: Drove me nuts to as I didn't change my Jenkins scripts and they just broke after upgrading.